# How to correctly use \newenvironment

Tags: macros, environments

I would like to use a `\newenvironment` in my .tex file. It should use a serif font and should be left aligned.

Can someone show me the correct syntax?

Comment: is the enviornment that you want to define the same as `\begin{flushleft}...\end{flushleft}` ?

Comment: Which serif font? `\newenvironment{foo}{\rmfamily}{}` should be enough

Comment: `\newenvironment{<environment-name>}{<code-at-begin>}{<code-at-end>}`. If you want to have arguments, you can use `\newenvironment{<name>}[<arg-count>]` and then the rest (similar to `\newcommand`). The arguments are only available in the begin-part.

Comment: could it be a right exmple?
\newenvironment{nico}{\begin{FlushLeft}{\end{FlushLeft}
    \begin{nico}
bla bla bla 
\end{nico}
\end{document

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are three ways of defining environments that use serif fonts (`\rmfamily` here in short) and aligning them to the left. The 3rd way with `\NewEnviron` uses `\sffamily` and alignment to the right in order to show the differences.

The `\vskip\baselineskip` is not necessary, just for visually separating them.

The regular way is `\newenvironment`, having

`\newenvironment{environmentname}[number of args][value of optional argument]{begin code}{end code}` -- the example here does not have arguments, so `[]` can be omitted there. Please note, that the arguments can not be accessed in the `{end code}` section.

With `\NewDocumentEnvironment` the syntax is 'similar':

`\NewDocumentEnvironment{environmentname}{argument specifications}{begin code}{end code}`  -- here, the arguments can be used in the end code section.

`\NewEnviron` from `environ` package is different in some aspects:

`\NewEnviron{environment name}[number of arguments][opt argument value]{environment start code\BODY}[environment end code}`.

You need the `\BODY` macro in order to display the environment content -- this is collected first in `\BODY`. The end code is optional here.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newenvironment{foo}{\rmfamily\flushleft}{\endflushleft}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{foobar}{}{\vskip\baselineskip\rmfamily\flushleft}{\endflushleft}

\NewEnviron{foobarbar}{\vskip\baselineskip\sffamily\flushright\BODY}[\endflushright]




\begin{document}
\begin{foo}
\blindtext
\end{foo}

\begin{foobar}
\blindtext
\end{foobar}

\begin{foobarbar}
\blindtext
\end{foobarbar}



\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update with some font package loading**

Just for example, I am using the `bookman` package for the `Bookman` font, which is a roman (serif) font by default -- there is no need to change `\rmfamily` then:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{bookman}

\newenvironment{foo}{\rmfamily\flushleft}{\endflushleft}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{foobar}{}{\vskip\baselineskip\rmfamily\flushleft}{\endflushleft}

\NewEnviron{foobarbar}{\vskip\baselineskip\sffamily\flushright\BODY}[\endflushright]




\begin{document}
\begin{foo}
\blindtext
\end{foo}

\begin{foobar}
\blindtext
\end{foobar}

\begin{foobarbar}
\blindtext
\end{foobarbar}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: wonderful! it works!
I would use another font family, because the one that I've declared (cinzel) do not write lowercase. Is it possible?

Comment: @RenatoP: You should be able to use any font inside the environments.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: @RenatoP: In most cases, it is sufficient to load the font package, assuming that it defines `\rmfamily` accordingly