# New environment in small font

Tags: fonts, environments

How do I define a new environment so that the text in it is all in small font, or in tiny font, say?

I have the example

```
\newenvironment{mysage}{\sageblock}{\endsageblock}
```

in mind, which usually has fixed-width output. (Yes, I still want fixed-width output, just in small font.)

I know about the commands `\small` an `\tiny` - I just wonder where to put them.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! See my answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417711/how-to-correctly-use-newenvironment -- replace `\rmfamily` with `\small`, so `\newenvironment{mysage}{\small\sageblock}{\endsageblock}` should work

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Not really: at least you need `\par` in front of `\small`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `sageblock` is based on `verbatim` of the homonymous package, you can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{mysage}
 {\preto\verbatim@font{\small}\sageblock}
 {\endsageblock}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Abc def ghi
\begin{sageblock}
aaa bbb ccc
\end{sageblock}
Abc def ghi
\begin{mysage}
aaa bbb ccc
\end{mysage}
Abc def ghi

\end{document}
```

[image]

A naïve definition such as

```
\newenvironment{mysage}
 {\small\sageblock}
 {\endsageblock}
```

would not work.

Comment: Thanks for calling my proposition `naïve` ... I was just too lazy in order to look what `\sageblock` does

Comment: Why wouldn't a naive definition work? It seems to work for me.

Comment: @HAHelfgott If you don't have a blank line before the environment, the line spacing would go awry.