# Example and exercise environment to stretch over following page

Tags: page-breaking, page

The following code gives me the output according the attached picture. At the bottom of the picture you can see that the example being explained is cut as the page is not enough long and that the rest of example that is cut doesn't continue over the following page. So how to stretch the content of both my *exemple* and *exercice* environments so the example or the exercise continues over the following page?

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=20cm, paperheight=29cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,arrows,chains,automata,shapes,matrix,positioning,scopes,calc,babel}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.9}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\colorbox{light-gray}{\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\phase}[1]{\par\medskip\textbf{#1}\par\nopagebreak}

\RequirePackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed} % Required for creating the theorem, definition, exercise and corollary boxes

\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{70,50,212} % Define the orange color used for highlighting throughout the book

\newmdenv[skipabove=7pt,
skipbelow=7pt,
rightline=false,
leftline=true,
topline=false,
bottomline=false,
backgroundcolor=ocre!10,
linecolor=ocre,
innerleftmargin=5pt,
innerrightmargin=5pt,
innertopmargin=5pt,
innerbottommargin=5pt,
leftmargin=0cm,
rightmargin=0cm,
linewidth=4pt]{eBox}

\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}

\newtheorem{exempleT}{Exemple}[chapter]
\newenvironment{exemple}% environment name
{
\par
    \begin{exempleT}
        %\par\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent
        %\hfill{\tiny\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}
        \par\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent
        \tiny\ensuremath{\blacksquare}
        \par\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent\ignorespaces
        %\ignorespacesafterend
    \end{exempleT}
}

\newtheorem{exerciceT}{Exercice}[chapter]
\newenvironment{exercice}% environment name
{
\par
    \begin{eBox}\begin{exerciceT}
        %\par\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent
        %\hfill{\tiny\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}
        %\par\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent
        \hfill{\color{ocre}\tiny\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}
        \par\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent\ignorespaces
        %\ignorespacesafterend
    \end{exerciceT}\end{eBox}
}

\begin{document}
            \begin{exercice}\label{exercice:deterministeVersNonDeterministe}
                Transformez l'automate non déterministe \code{A = (Q,$\Sigma,\delta$,s,F)} de la figure~\ref{exemple:afnd} en un automate fini déterministe \code{A' = (Q',$\Sigma',\delta'$,s',F')}.\\

                Construction de l'automate fini déterministe \code{A'}:\\

                \begin{enumerate}
                    \item Si \code{Q} $= \{1, 2, 3\}$ est l'ensemble des états de l'automate \code{A} alors:\\
                                        \code{Q'} est l'ensemble des sous ensembles de \code{Q}.\\
                                        \code{Q'} $= \{\varnothing, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{2,3\}, \{1,2,3\} \}$.\\
                    \item $\Sigma$ ne change pas. Donc $\Sigma' = \Sigma$.
                    \item Si $\delta$ est la fonction de transition de \code{A}, alors $\delta'$ est la fonction de transition de \code{A'}. $\delta'$ est la fonction de transition suivante, et est un sous ensemble de \code{Q'} $\times \Sigma \times$ \code{Q'}:
                        \begin{multicols}{2}
                            $\delta = \{\\
                            \delta(\varnothing, a)=\varnothing$\\           
                            $\delta(\{1\}, a)=\varnothing$\\
                            $\delta(\{2\}, a)=\varnothing$\\
                            $\delta(\{3\}, a)=\{1,2\}$\\
                            $\delta(\{1,2\}, a)=\varnothing$\\
                            $\delta(\{1,3\},a)=\{1,2\}$\\
                            $\delta(\{2,3\},a)=\{1,2\}$\\
                            $\delta(\{1,2,3\}, a)=\{1,2\}$

                        \columnbreak

                        \vline \hspace{1cm}

                            $\delta(\{\varnothing,b\})=\varnothing$\\
                            $\delta(\{1\},b)=\{2,3\}$\\
                            $\delta(\{2\},b)=\varnothing$\\
                            $\delta(\{3\},b)=\varnothing$\\
                            $\delta(\{1,2\},b)=\{2,3\}$\\
                            $\delta(\{1,3\},b)=\{2,3\}$\\
                            $\delta(\{2,3\},b)=\varnothing$\\
                            $\delta(\{1,2,3\},b)=\{2,3\}\}$
                        \end{multicols}

                    \item \code{s} ne change pas. \code{s} étant l'état initial de \code{A}, il demeure l'état initial de \code{A'}. Si \code{s'} est l'état initial de \code{A'}, alors \code{s' = s = 1}.
                    \item \code{F} étant l'ensemble des états finaux de \code{A} alors \code{F'} est l'ensemble des états finaux de \code{A'}.
                        Les états finaux du nouvel automate \code{A'} sont tous des sous ensembles des états contenant l'état $3$.

                        Donc \code{F'} $= \{\{3\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$\\
                        D'où le diagramme des transitions suivant:
                        \begin{center}
                            \begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth, shorten >=1pt, auto, node distance=2.5cm, initial text = Début]
                                \node[initial, state](4){$1$};
                                \node[state](1)[above left=of 4]{$2$};
                                \node[state](2)[right=of 1]{$\varnothing$};
                                \node[state, accepting](3)[right=of 2]{$3$};
                                \node[state, accepting](5)[right=of 4]{${\{2, 3\}}$};
                                \node[state](6)[right of=5]{${\{1, 2\}}$};
                                \node[state, accepting](7)[below=of 5]{${\{1, 3\}}$};
                                \node[state, accepting](8)[below=of 6]{${\{1, 2, 3\}}$};

                                \path[->] (1) edge node {a}   (2);
                                \path[->] (1) edge [swap] node {b}   (2);

                                \path[->] (2) edge [loop above] node {a, b}   (2);

                                \path[->] (3) edge node {b}   (2);
                                \path[->] (3) edge node {a}   (6);

                                \path[->] (4) edge node {a}   (2);
                                \path[->] (4) edge node {b}   (5);
                                \path[->] (5) edge node {b}   (2);
                                \path[->] ({5}) edge node {a}   (6);
                                \path[->] ({6}) edge node {b}   (5);
                                \path[->] ({6}) edge node {b}   (2);

                                \path[->] (7) edge node {b}   (5);
                                \path[->] (7) edge node {a}   (6);

                                \path[->] (8) edge node {a}   (6);
                                \path[->] (8) edge node {b}   (5);
                            \end{tikzpicture}
                        \end{center}

                        Si on supprime les états qui ne peuvent être atteints, on obtient l'AFD suivant:

                    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth, shorten >=1pt, auto, node distance=3cm, initial text = Début]
                        \node[initial, state](A){$\{1\}$};
                        \node[state](B)[above right=of A]{$\varnothing$};
                        \node[state, accepting](C)[below of=B]{$\{2, 3\}$};
                        \node[state](D)[right of=C]{$\{1, 2\}$};

                        \path[->] (A) edge node {a}   (B);
                        \path[->] (B) edge [loop above] node {a, b}   (B);
                        \path[->] (A) edge node {b}  (C);
                        \path[->] (C) edge [bend right] node {a}   (D);
                        \path[->] (C) edge node {b}   (B);
                        \path[->] (D) edge [bend right] node {b}   (C);
                        \path[->] (D) edge node {a}   (B);
                    \end{tikzpicture}

                    Le langage que cet automate accepte est le suivant:\\

                    \begin{center}
                        $\{b(ab)^n$ : $n \in \mathbb{N} \, \}$
                    \end{center}
                \end{enumerate}
            \end{exercice}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your MWE seems off with the box stuck at the top, but the text does page break appropriately.  If I rewrite your `\newenvironment`s to follow `\newenvironment{<name>}{<\begin{ebox} etc.>}{<etc. \end{ebox}>}` (see [How to correctly use \newenvironment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/417711/106162)) it looks as intended, breaking over two pages.  Does that work?

Comment: Off-topic: Note that `mdframed` can lead to empty boxes after a pagebreak, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/590554/237192. That's the reason why I switched to `tcolorbox` (which can also be breakable).

Comment: @Dai Bowen, with the same exact code I have posted inside the whole book code, I get exactly what we see on the picture.

Comment: @Dai Bowen, I mean breaking over two pages actually doesn't work.

Comment: @Dai Bowen, is that the right way to write my exercice environment? `\newtheorem{exempleT}{Exemple}[chapter]
\newenvironment{exemple}% environment name
{
\par
 \begin{exempleT}
  \par\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent
  \tiny\ensuremath{\blacksquare}
}
{
  \par\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent\ignorespaces
    \end{exempleT}
}`

Comment: That looks more like what I imagine you want yes, I doubt it relates to the lack of page break though

Comment: The changes doesn't affect at all the problem questioned. The lack of page break is still occurring and is really and issue for me.

Comment: @cProg didn't think it would, without code to reproduce (when I compile your MWE I get a page break at a perfectly reasonable place) there's not much I can suggest (I'd echo the `tcolorbox` rec though).  I take it your real document gives no errors (at all, anywhere) and no warnings around the failed break?